# How to go from second activity to third activity or fourth activity based on first activity data (Radio button clicked)?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, sharedpreferences, bundles

I have four activities say java files - activity1.java, activity2.java, activity3.java, activity4.java and xml files - activity_1.xml, activity_2.xml, activity_3.xml, activity_4.xml

Now in activity1 - I have a radio group with two radio buttons and a button to go to activity2

Now in activity2 - I have a button to go to activity3 or activity4 based on which radio button is clicked in activity1.

I can delete activity2 and use if condition in activity1 to go to activity3 or 4 But I definitely need activity2

I am not familiar with bundles, shared preferences

How? Any help in this regard

Answer (score 0):

You can just use an intent and pass on values between activities. In first activity:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("someName", valueOfRadioButton);
 startActivity(intent);
```

In the `onCreate` of the next activity you can retrieve the value you passed like this (for an Integer):

```
 getIntent().getIntExtra("someName", someDefaultValue);
```

Now you have a variable to query. Depending on the value, you launch whatever activity you like.

Comment: can you please tell me about valueOfRadioButton and someDefaultValue , what kind? any example

Comment: Default value is for when a parameter is not available, ie some scenario where you launched the activity, but did not pass on an intent. If it can't find the value stored under `someName`, it will use the default value, whichever you specify. As for the `valueOfRadioButton`, you must have a value indicating which radio button is checked. You can just pass this on as the `valueOfRadioButton`. Intents can pass on a lot of simple data types.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Intent startSecondActivityIntent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.java);
Intent.putExtra("nameOfValue",value);
startActivity(startSecondActivityIntent);
```

Then you can get this value:

```
getIntent().getIntExtra("nameOfValue",defaultValue);
```

Or you can use SharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("nameOfPreferences",MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putString("nameOfValue",value);
    editor.commit();
```

And get this value in other activity:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("nameOfPreferences",MODE_PRIVATE);
String value = sp.getString("nameOfValue",defaultValue);
```

Comment: How can i use if condition for first activity in the second activity because there are two radio buttons in first activity and depending on which radio button is clicked , the user has to go from second to third or fourth activity